# Dynamic Table Filtering Gives Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I followed a pretty simple VBA dynamic filtering tutorial for Tables - but I have no VBA experience and am unable to figure out why I'm receiving Error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error.

For reference, I have a Table in my Active Worksheet called "AcronymList"

My VBA filter code is as follows:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
'Filter acronyms in AcronymList Table.
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("AcronymList").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:="*" & [A3] & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Any time I add / remove text from my A3 ActiveX TextBox, the error occurs.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: `xlfiltervalues` is for when you supply an array of filter values. You aren't doing that so remove the operator argument.

Comment: Hi Rory, I removed the Operator argument as you suggested and I am receiving the same error.

Comment: `Criteria1:=`, not `Criteria`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small typo: `Criteria1:=...` instead of `Criteria:=...`
See the [`Range.AutoFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel) method for more detail.

Note that you shouldn't use the Operator argument as mentioned by @Rory in the comments.